# padding,cellpadding doesn't work with jquery ajax load

Tags: jquery, css

When i load a page inside a DIV with Jquery load function, table cellpadding and padding css attribute on table tag doesn't work.

Is this a normal behavior ?

Code to load page

```
$("#ajax_content").load("page.php", function () {
    })
```

Table tag on the page.php

```
<table cellpadding="2px" style="background-color: white;width: 550px; height: 34px;padding:10px">
```

Thanks

EDIT:

I found the problem ! 
In the main page that i am loading page.php to there is a css code like this

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
```

problem is that and it works great now after i deleted it.

Comment: This is not normal no.  Please post some code so we have a better chance of helping you

Comment: you can answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem ! In the main page that i am loading page.php to there is a css code like this

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
```

problem is that and it works great now after i deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table cellpadding="2" style="background-color: white;width: 550px; height: 34px;padding:10px">
```

`cellpadding="2"` instead `cellpadding="2px"`

and `padding:10px"` style for the table is not going to work on IE7 and less.

Comment: thanks nice warning for IE7 and less i will keep this in my mind